# C# LINQ accessing another property within a LINQ SELECT statement (method)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a question which refers to whether it's possible to access another property in LINQ in order to set another property's value in LINQ:

```
  var v = ctx.myTableItems
          .Where(x => x.id== anotherid)
          .Select(e => new MyViewModel
          {
            Title = e.Title,
            CurrentPrice = e.CurrenctPrice.Value,

            ItemID =  e.ItemID.ToString(),
            Transactions= e.Transactions,
            Sales = 
            })
            .Where(x=>x.Sales>0);
```

So check this out guys, when I was setting my Transactions property I set the transactions collection in my previous line, and now I'd like to set my sales propert with the Transactions property that was assigned in a previous line:

```
  Transactions= e.Transactions,
  Sales = e.Transactions.Sum(x=>x.Quantity) // Normaly I'd do it like this
```

But I wanted to try out something like this:

```
 Sales = Transactions.Sum(x=>x.Quantity) // is this doable ?
```

So my question here is, is it possible to set another property within the select statement with a previously property's value? In my case it's Transactions collection ?

Is this doable, if so , how?

P.S. I'm trying to figure if this is doable because if I could use this previously set property's value , then I would avoid performing 2 unnecesary queries on my Transactions table in DB?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the previous value because you dont want to call e.Transactions.Sum() for every item.

Just add a method to MyViewModel

```
public double GetSales()
{
 return Transactions.Sum(x=>x.Quantity);
}

//at the end of your code use:
.Where(x=>x.GetSales()>0);
```

Comment: Should I do this at the select statement as well ?

Comment: No just remove the Sales Member and replace it with the method.

Comment: Ah okay but how am I gonna fill the Transactions collection for each item that I have in the DB ? That's the part that confusing me ... Because I don't have Transactions collection in my ViewModel class? P.S. Each item has a different set of transactions ... So I guess the way I did was required?

Comment: If you have doubts you can just use Transactions.ToArray() and loop with a for loop. This way all your data is local and not enumerated every time ;)

Comment: Max good point thx, but how would I then translate this expression to SQL if I wouldn't first cast the query to list and then perform it like this ? Because I've tried it like this and it says the expression cannot be translated... ?